# Is a comma necessary after these speech tags?

Tags: commas, direct-speech

> 'Hello,' said Peter, with a smile on his face.
>
> 'Hello,' replied John, as he closed the book.

Are the commas after "Peter" and "John" correct? Are there differences between British and American rules in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

The commas after Peter and John are certainly correct. I'm not aware of any differences in American usage.

Comment: The only difference in US usage would be double quotation marks. The location and use of the commas in those two specific sentences is the same.